# Is there a way to get terraform provider's attribute and store it as a local variable?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a provider defined in the topmost module, is there a way to access its attributes inside a child module?

An example:

The topmost module:

```
provider "google" {
    project = "foo"
}
module "child" {
    source = "./child"
}
```

Child module:

```
locals {
    foo = google.project // this won't work (probably because it clashes with alias access syntax)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, you can't reference providers like this. There were already few requests for this, e.g. [here](https://github.com/terraform-provider-openstack/terraform-provider-openstack/issues/785) or [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/9221).

Instead, in your case you can use data source:

```
data "google_project" "project" {}

locals {
    foo = data.google_project.project.project_id
}
```

or make the project id a variable:

```
variable "project_id" {
   default = "foo"
}

provider "google" {
    project =  var.project_id
}

locals {
    foo = var.project_id
}
```